# Как попарно суммировать значения двух разных массивов?

Tags: javascript

У меня имеется два массива:

```
var Specifications = [0, 12, 4, 9]
var Specifications2 = [12, 4, 8, 1]
```

Нужно сложить элементы массивов `Specifications` и `Specifications2` так, чтобы получилось:

```
Specifications3 = [12, 16, 12, 10]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let Specifications = [0, 12, 4, 9]
let Specifications2 = [12, 4, 8, 1]

let sum = Specifications.map((num, idx) => num + Specifications2[idx]);

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Проверка на одинаковую длину массивов не помешала бы

```
let result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < Specifications.length; i++) {
   result[i] = Specifications[i] + Specifications2[i];
}
```